# How to "leap of faith" when using recursion?

Tags: recursion

For me when making a recursive method. I always need to spend a lot of time to do it, because I will make some test cases and to see whether my recursive case works and to draw a stack diagram. However, when I ask other about it, they just say that I need to believe myself it will work. How am I suppose to believe that if you don't know what is going on in the recursive case?

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with studying a problem in depth, as long as you don't become incapable of executing the plan or program. There is a free-swinging aspect as well; where while you're studiously analyzing, someone else may deal with inevitable and predictable failure and tear down and rebuild until it works (called prototyping).

Comment: I mean, when doing recursion, it is said that you know it is going to work when calling its own method. But I just find it hard to understand. How do we know it is going to work without really know what will happen in these recursive stacks.

Comment: I suspect most people eventually (or intuitively, in some cases) simply can visualize it in their mind.

Comment: @LeonMa you do know what's happening because you were the one defining the logic for it. It does exactly what you told it to do, so as long as you know what you are doing, there should be no ambiguity about how the function will behave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *define* what is going on in the recursive case, just as you define the rest of the method.  Imagine someone else wrote a method to do what the one you are writing does; you wouldn't have a problem calling that, would you?  The only difference is that *you* are that method's author, and it just happens to be the one being written.

For example: I am writing the following method:

```
// Sort array a[i..j-1] in ascending order
method sort_array( a, i, j ) {
  ..
}
```

The base case is easy:

```
  if ( i >= j-1 ) // there is at most one element to be sorted
    return;       // a[i..j-1] is already sorted
```

Now, when that *isn't* true, I could do the following:

```
  else {
    k = index_of_max( a, i, j );
    swap( a, j-1, k );
```

At this point, I know that `a[j-1]` has the correct value, so I just need to sort what comes before it -- fortunately, I have a method to do just that:

```
    sort_array( a, i, j-1 );
  }
```

No leap of faith is required; I know that recursive call will work because I wrote the method to do just that.